# How long does the whitelisting process typically take?

Tags: google-schemas

We are planning on using schema's in our confirmation emails to our users to enable Google Now cards as well as provide an action for users to modify their reservations.  I am curious how long the approval process typically takes.  We've already sent our test email to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com and filled out the registration form [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1).  I'm curious how long the application process typically takes before we should expect to hear something back.

Answer (score 0):

This process took less than 2 weeks in my case.